# More elegant/efficient solution to browse through an array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an array of lists and want to correlate every list with each other like this:

```
Table[Table[Correlation[list[[y]], list[[x]]], {x, 1, Length[list]}], {y,1, Length[list]}];
```

I take the first list and correlate it with all others asf. I pretty much assume, this is not a very elegant and efficient code, so I wanted to ask for some alternatives. How would you guys do it?

Comment: `list = Permutations@Range@3; Correlation @@@ Subsets[list, {2}]` ?

Comment: Possibly related and/or helpful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8928/121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you mean by "browse through an array" but from my best guess you might try:

```
array = RandomInteger[9, {50, 50}];

Pane[TableForm @ array, {500, 400}, Scrollbars -> True]
```

[image]

---

Since this is not the meaning you intended here is another:

```
list = {a, b, c, d};

Outer[f, list, list]
```

> ```
> {{f[a, a], f[a, b], f[a, c], f[a, d]},
>  {f[b, a], f[b, b], f[b, c], f[b, d]},
>  {f[c, a], f[c, b], f[c, c], f[c, d]},
>  {f[d, a], f[d, b], f[d, c], f[d, d]}}
> ```

```
f @@@ Tuples[list, 2]
```

> ```
>  {f[a, a], f[a, b], f[a, c], f[a, d], f[b, a], f[b, b], f[b, c], f[b, d],
>   f[c, a], f[c, b], f[c, c], f[c, d], f[d, a], f[d, b], f[d, c], f[d, d]}
> ```

Note that [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Outer.html) produces a table of values (nested lists) while [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tuples.html) produces a flat list.

See also: [how to efficiently apply function to all pairs of a set (and collect the results)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9537/121)

Comment: or `ArrayPlot[array, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]` for the more visual people out there :)

Comment: @PinguinDirk Of course that would be better for numeric data; this is intended as a generic method, where elements are arbitrary expressions.

Comment: sure, just kidding - one can only guess what he wants, at this point

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to call it. I meant getting to every value of the array, e.g. for multiplying or correlating all values of an array with each other.

Comment: @holistic Mathematica has a lot of ways to do that kind of things. If you edit your question and post a few examples of your needs I'm sure you'll get more specific answers. Mr.Wiz here interpreted "browsing" as "looking at", as most of us did

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I edited the question :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think he means "browse" as in the `Scan` sense... walk through the list. What OP wants is just `Outer[Correlation, list, list]` (possibly fix levels... didn't try), which is most likely a millionth duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Another option might be to use `TableView` This gives the row number and column number on the sides as well. This is undocumented still as of Version 9.01, but it is there.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
array = RandomInteger[9, {50, 50}];
TableView[array]
```

[image]

Comment: I see they've improved `TableView` since v7; looks nice. +1

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
Correlation @ Transpose @ list
```